# change height between month react native Calendar

Tags: react-native, calendar, react-native-stylesheet, react-native-calendars

I'm inserting a calendar on my project, but I'm trying to reduce the space between months, but I can't find where to change

[Where I want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjBBw.png)

Here is the code

```
<CalendarList
      theme={{
        calendarBackground: '#9C9C9C',
        todayTextColor: '#FFF',
        dayTextColor: '#FFF',
        textDisabledColor: '#F5F5F5',
        textDayFontWeight: '500',
        monthTextColor: '#FFF',
        textMonthFontFamily: scrollDown ? 'inter-bold' : 'inter-regular',
        'stylesheet.calendar.main': {
          dayContainer: {
            borderColor: '#B4B4B4',
            borderWidth: 1,
            flex: 1,
            padding: 10,
            backgroundColor: '#B9B9B9',
          },
          emptyDayContainer: {
            flex: 1,
            padding: 11,
          },
          week: {
            marginTop: 0,
            marginBottom: 0,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-around',
          },
        },
        'stylesheet.calendar.header': {
          header: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            marginLeft: 10,
            marginTop: 5,
          },
          monthText: {
            alignSelf: 'stretch',
            textAlign: 'left',
            color: 'white',
            
            
          },
        },
      }}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you find any answers regarding this?

Comment: You can use calendarStyle of CalendarList's property. It's work for me. Hope it may help you.  calendarStyle={{marginBottom: -30}}